# Pass parameter to Swashbuckle OperationFilter

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I have an action method that requires a custom header. I found this code to add a custom header to the UI.

```
public class AddRequiredHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters == null)
            operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

        operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "Foo-Header",
                @in = "header",
                type = "string",
                required = true
            });
    }
}
```

But I want to be able to use this in other methods that may require different custom header name. Something like this, where I can pass the custom header name to the constructor.

```
public class CustomHeaderOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        private string _headerName;

        public CustomHeaderOperationFilter(string headerName)
        {
            _headerName = headerName;
        }

        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            if (operation.parameters == null)
                operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = _headerName,
                type = "string",
                @in = "header",
                required = true,
            });
        }
    }
```

And I only want to assign it to a specific Action method, so I was hoping I could decorate the action method with an attribute like this:

```
[SwaggerOperationFilter<CustomHeaderOperationFilter>("custom-header-name")]
```

But unfortunately I can only pass the type of the filter to the attribute. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

After looking at Swashbuckle code, I decided to create a custom SwaggerCustomHeaderOperationFilterAttribute

```
public class SwaggerCustomHeaderOperationFilterAttribute : BaseCustomSwaggerOperationFilterAttribute
{
    public SwaggerCustomHeaderOperationFilterAttribute(string headerName, string headerDescription, bool isRequired)
    {
        OperationFilter = new CustomHeaderOperationFilter(headerName, headerDescription, isRequired);
    }
}
```

Inheriting from:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class BaseCustomSwaggerOperationFilterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IOperationFilter OperationFilter { get; protected set; }
}
```

And custom ApplyCustomSwaggerOperationFilterAttributes:

```
public class ApplyCustomSwaggerOperationFilterAttributes : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var attributes = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<BaseCustomSwaggerOperationFilterAttribute>();

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            attribute.OperationFilter.Apply(operation, schemaRegistry, apiDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

This way I can decorate my Action method with

```
[SwaggerCustomHeaderOperationFilter("header-name", "header-description", true)]
```